# XSD Validation Error when mandatory element is missing from sequence complex type

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have an XSD and incorrect XML.

The XSD has a complex type with a **sequence** of elements. All those elements are **mandatory**. (The XSD is maintained by a 3rd party and **can't** be changed)

The incorrect XML is missing one element.

When I validate the XML against the XSD using C#, the expected error is "the 'XXX' element is expected". But actually, it also tells me "the element has invalid child element". I'm not sure what should I do.

To help you understand my question, I'll show you an example:

```
<!-- Incorrect XML -->
<class>
  <el1>222</el1>
  <el3>222</el3>
</class>

<!-- XSD -->
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="class">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:short" name="el1" />
        <xs:element type="xs:short" name="el2" />
        <xs:element type="xs:short" name="el3"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The real but unexpected validation errors are something like below:

> The element 'class' has invalid child element 'el3'. List of possible elements expected: 'el2'.

The expected errors are:

> List of possible elements expected: 'el2'.

Comment: I don't view this error as necessarily being unexpected.  The error output is telling you that it hit an `<el3>` element when it really expected an `<el2>` element instead.  And from the point of view of validation, it is still failing when it should, just with an error message which you didn't expect.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I think you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the message.  It's *not* saying that `el3` cannot ever be a child of `class`.  It's saying that `el3` ***is invalid at the point at which it was encountered it in the process of parsing.***

In other words, as stated,

> The element 'class' has invalid child element 'el3'.

is correct.

On the other hand, the way you're interpreting the message,

> The element 'class' can never have child element 'el3'.

would indeed be incorrect.  However, since it doesn't actually say that, the diagnostic message is fine as is.

Comment: Thanks @kjhughes. However, I didn't interpreted the message as you said. I know the message _The element 'class' has invalid child element 'el3'._ is correct,  I just hope if there's any chance I only get a single message said _List of possible elements expected: 'el2'._

Comment: Perhaps you meant *desired*, not *expected* then.  The answer to your question then is, yes, if you wish to override the default error handler behavior, you can write whatever message you'd like; frankly, however, I don't see it being worth the effort here.

Comment: Yes, I have persuaded my colleagues to just leave as it is. BTW, as you mentioned _"you can write whatever message you'd like"_, it'd be great if you could give me some hints or links that I can look at?

Comment: Hint: Set a custom `ValidationEventHandler`:  `doc.Validate(xmlSchemaSet, new ValidationEventHandler(CustomHandler), true);`